# Go - map value doesn't update

Tags: go

I have some sample code here (runnable here: http://play.golang.org/p/86_EBg5_95)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type X struct {
    Y   int
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[int]X)
    var x *X
    if _, ok := m[0]; !ok {
        z := X{}
        m[0] = z
        x = &z
    }

    x.Y = 10
    fmt.Println(m[0].Y)
    fmt.Println(x.Y)
}
```

Basically: what am I missing here? Shouldn't `m[0].Y` be `10` as well?

Comment: Pretty sure `m[0] = z` makes a copy

Comment: Uhm, well... Is there a way to get m[0]'s address then?

Comment: @Andrew: No, because "maps grow to accommodate the number of items stored in them." [Map types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` point to `z` while `m[0]` is a copy of `z` (it's a `map[int]X` and not a `map[int]*X`), so updating `x.Y` wont update `m[0]`

I'm not sure what you want to do, but here `m` is a map containing pointers:

```
func main() {
    m := make(map[int]*X)
    var x *X
    if _, ok := m[0]; !ok {
        z := X{}
        m[0] = &z
        x = &z
    }

    x.Y = 10
    fmt.Println(m[0].Y)
    fmt.Println(x.Y)
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I initially wanted and already done it like that. Thanks anyway!